# Ndk toolchain complaining about missing lrt option

Tags: android-ndk, librt

Getting below error on NDK-build

/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-            x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lrt

I updated Android.mk for absolute path of lrt but issue did not resolve

My Android.mk is here

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)    
THIS_PATH  := $(LOCAL_PATH)    
include $(CLEAR_VARS)    
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES   := off    
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES  := off    
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE         := STATIC    
OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK_HOME := /home/Ravikant/Desktop/OpenCV-android-sdk    
include $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK_HOME)/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk    
OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR        := $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK_HOME)/sdk/native/jni/include    
OPENCV_LIBS_DIR           := $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK_HOME)/sdk/native/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)  
OPENCV_3RD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR := $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK_HOME)/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)

LOCAL_MODULE    := myModule    
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -w    
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := searchPath.cpp auxiliary.cpp      
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -fopenmp -llog -ljnigraphics -L$(OPENCV_LIBS_DIR)    
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += prebuilt_for_opencv_java    
    -lopencv_core         \    
    -lopencv_highgui      \    
    -lopencv_objdetect    \    
    -lopencv_imgproc      \    
    -lopencv_imgcodecs    \    
    -lopencv_photo    

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)



LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := prebuilt_for_opencv_java

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(OPENCV_LIBS_DIR)/libopencv_java3.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Can anyone tell whether its ndk configuration issue or something diffrent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have encountered similar issue earlier.

> -fopenmp flag implies both the -lgomp and -lrt

So just replace `-fopenmp` with `-lgomp`
and it should work then